# Can Raspberry Pi B+ use a card (with Debian) configured/used with "old" Raspberry Pi B?

Tags: hardware, sd-card, operating-systems, compatibility

So, I've several SDs bearing several OSes (Debian, Occidentalis, Raspbmc) for my several Pi Bs and my question is two-fold:

- can I (safely) boot B+ Pi from those cards w/o a risk they will be corrupted/changed (without me doing the `sudo apt-get update/upgrade` explicitly)?
- if I do `sudo apt-get update/upgrade` on B+, will there be any changes (to kernel etc) that will make the OS unusable when returned to my "old" Bs?

*(GPIO usage/configuration is not part of this question)*

Comment: Absolutely,. You can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your Model B, you will need to put in the SD card, boot up and do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then it will boot on your B+. If I remember correctly, the firmware was changed and the upgrade is needed (if older than June 20 2014).

Source: https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-raspberry-pi-model-b-plus-plus-differences-vs-model-b/what-doesnt-work-anymore#you-may-need-a-new-kernel-slash-firmware

When I first got my B+, I tried a SD card with an older image. I booted up and the keyboard and Ethernet did not work. Once I upgraded the image (in my B), it worked on my B+.

So to answer your question; it will not harm anything on your B.