# RPi B v2.0 not accepting keyboards

Tags: raspbian, usb, keyboard

I'm using a RPi B v2.0 ("Made in the UK" with the P5 connector). I've installed Raspbian to an 8GB SDHC class 4 card and can boot (the display shows nice boot log). When measuring between TP1 and TP2, 4.9V are displayed (without SD card and not connected to the monitor 5.0V are displayed). This voltage does not change when I connect my Cherry G230 keyboard (labeled with 5V max 40mA). [This 5V/2A PSU](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00IMU7TF4/ref=s9_simh_gw_p23_d0_i1?pf_rd_m=A3JWKAKR8XB7XF&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=19PYBYNMKCDBNJ3332M3&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=455353687&pf_rd_i=301128) is used.

It's booting until the configuration screen of Raspbian, but no matter what key I press nothing happens, not even the LEDs (Caps, Num, Scroll) can be toggled. After approx. 2min (no matter whether the keyboard is plugged in or not) a red-orange square is shown in the top-right corner of the screen (over-heat indicator?). I've also tried a different remote keyboard which, as the above mentioned Cherry one works fine on another RPi B+, but to no avail.

Is there some way to configure the Raspbian on a PC or using a RPi B+, so I don't need an keyboard any more, but can do further stuff using SSH?

Comment: What happens if you boot it *without* any keyboard plugged in and watch it for a few minutes?  Does the same overheating indicator appear?

Comment: "After approx. 2min (**no matter whether the keyboard is plugged in or not**) a red-orange square is shown in the top-right corner of the screen (over-heat indicator?)."

Comment: If that's with nothing attached, it implies something's wrong w/ the pi itself.  AFAICT, there's no reason you should not be able to boot it with a card prepared on the B+ (mine's in the mail, but I'm pretty sure about this), so you could try that (prepare the card fresh on the B+, don't use whatever card you have for it already in case whatever's wrong has a negative effect on it).

Comment: Certainly the inverse is true: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23192/can-raspberry-pi-b-use-a-card-with-debian-configured-used-with-old-raspberr

Answer (score 1):

See [How to start up with a raspberry pi b+ with a laptop](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/25934/how-to-start-up-with-a-raspberry-pi-b-with-a-laptop) for a possible method of configuring the Pi without a keyboard/screen.

<strike>Your problems may be power related.  The red-orange square in the top-right of the screen indicates that your power supply has dropped below about 4.63 volts.</strike>

You are right, the red-orange square is an over temperature warning. It means the chip has reached 85'C (and any overclock will be disabled).

Comment: Not on the B, because it doesn't have the undervoltage detector.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately, the network connection does not work either - not even the light on the network switch lights up after more than 2min.

Comment: @Milliways I wonder if the firmware has been updated to use the 3V3 voltage level on a B?  But, as you say the B has different circuitry.

Comment: @Milliways I was wrong.  It is an over temperature warning as the OP thought.

Comment: How comes that over-temperatur occurs after 2min doing nearly nothing in a normal heated environment (~20°C room temperature)?

Comment: I have no idea.  I'd run top from the command line and see what is going on.  Perhaps your Pi is damaged.

Comment: @ThomasS. There's two kinds of "doing nearly nothing" -- the idle kind in which case the hardware is idle, and the busy kind, in which case it is in fact busy (doing nothing).  You can completely max out a processor doing nothing (symptomatic of a problem or error), in which case it will slowly heat up.  However, it could also be wrongly detecting something.  If it is really 85 °C you should be able to tell by touching the processor.

Comment: The board becomes quiet hot, especially in the center.

Comment: @ThomasS. What does top report?  Is any process busy?  What does vcgencmd measure_temp report?

Comment: I can neither get the keyboard working nor login using SSH.